# Is this question too broad? "What are his wedding vows?"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closing-questions, vote-to-reopen

I'm looking for [what The Doctor said for his weddings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/221785/what-were-the-doctor-s-wedding-vows), some think it's a broad question. For a week now the question seems to be in limbo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the major issue was the disconnect between the title (asking what a Timelord says on their wedding day, presumably on Gallifrey) versus the body that asked what the Doctor (hardly an average Timelord at the best of times) said in his vows, presumably to an alien woman, in a ceremony on an alien planet.

In its present form, with the title finally agreeing with the body content, it's not too broad and I've cast the final vote to reopen it.